# Conditional insert in trigger

Tags: mysql

I am having some problem in implementing trigger with conditional insert statements. The piece of code I had tried which works without conditional statement is

```
CREATE TRIGGER TR_BI_USERS after insert on USERS for each row 
  insert into PERMISSION(per_id,role_id,page_id,allow_y_n,created_by) 
  select d.user_id,d.role_id,c.page_id,'Y',d.created_by 
  from USERS as d cross join resource c 
  where d.user_id=new.user_id and d.role_id=1;
```

However when I try the similar looking trigger with conditional statement, I am getting errors. The code I tried looks like this

```
CREATE TRIGGER TR_BI_USERS after insert on tourism_web.USERS for each row 
  begin 
    if new.role_id=1 then 
      insert into PERMISSION(per_id,role_id,page_id,allow_y_n,created_by) 
      select d.user_id,d.role_id,c.page_id,'Y',d.created_by 
      from USERS as d cross join resource c 
      where d.user_id=new.user_id; 
    else 
      insert into PERMISSION(per_id,role_id,page_id,allow_y_n,created_by) 
      select d.user_id,d.role_id,c.page_id,'N',d.created_by 
      from USERS as d cross join resource c 
      where d.user_id=new.user_id;
    end if;
  end;
```

Please suggest me what should I ammend in the later part of code to make it work. Thanks.

Comment: "I am getting errors". You should include the errors in your question.

Comment: Did you put a `DELIMITER` statement before this? If not, the first `;` will end the entire `CREATE TRIGGER` statement, in the middle of the `BEGIN` and `IF` blocks.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Barmar for giving the tip on delimiter. I tried with defining delimiter and now my trigger is working great. Thanks once again. :)

Answer (score 0):

When you write a trigger or procedure that contains multiple statements, you need to change the query delimiter first:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER TR_BI_USERS after insert on tourism_web.USERS for each row 
  begin 
    if new.role_id=1 then 
      insert into PERMISSION(per_id,role_id,page_id,allow_y_n,created_by) 
      select d.user_id,d.role_id,c.page_id,'Y',d.created_by 
      from USERS as d cross join resource c 
      where d.user_id=new.user_id; 
    else 
      insert into PERMISSION(per_id,role_id,page_id,allow_y_n,created_by) 
      select d.user_id,d.role_id,c.page_id,'N',d.created_by 
      from USERS as d cross join resource c 
      where d.user_id=new.user_id;
    end if;
  end;
DELIMITER ;
```